# Nuxt.js could not found component with errors "Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined."

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vue-router, nuxtjs

I am having problems with my Nuxt.js site.
I have defined a page, with a dynamic **slug** param, like this:

`/solutions/:slug`

If I visit the page directly in the browser, it loads correctly!
But if I click the nuxt-link in my NavBar component, I get the following error in the console, and the page does not load:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619

[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

found in

---> <Anonymous>
       <Nuxt>
         <Layouts/default.vue> at layouts/default.vue
           <Root>
```

I have a default layout file that looks like this:

**layouts/default.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <NavBar />
    <Nuxt />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import NavBar from "~/components/Layout/NavBar"

export default {
  components: {
    NavBar,
  },
}
</script>
```

My navbar contains the following nuxt-link:

**components/Layout/NavBar.vue**

```
<template>
  <b-navbar wrapper-class="container" fixed-top>
    <template slot="end">

      <nuxt-link
        :to="{
          name: 'solutions-slug',
          params: { slug: 'performance' },
        }"
        class="navbar-item"
        target="self"
      >
        <span class="icon is-medium">
          <i class="ic ic--larger ic-b1-graph-bars-chart-rise" />
        </span>
        <span class="label">
          Performance
        </span>
      </nuxt-link>

    </template>
  </b-navbar>
</template>
```

I have a page, defined by the slug param:

**pages/solutions/_slug.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="solution">
    This is my solution page.
  </div>
</template>
```

I am trying to understand why clicking the nuxt-link fails to load the page, even though I see the URL change in the browser correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the problem is not related to anything described above.

First, check if your configuration is correct. I see you are using 'nuxtjs/content' module, so you are probably using Contentful as well. In the past, I have encountered a similar situation ('Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined' issue) due to incorrect installation of the 'dotenv' module that I used to store variables.

In my case, the application did not load variables from the .env file. As a consequence, they went to the Contentful client unidentified and caused the js error. For some reason, this error did not always appear in the console. Instead, the above-mentioned Warn appeared.

Make sure you have the 'dotenv' module correctly installed (if you use it). I remember that in my case it was necessary to install 'nuxtjs/dotenv' instead of the usual dotenv.

Let me know if this is the case. Good luck

Comment: Genius!!! It was dotenv that tripped me up here... Everything else was a red herring. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2):

After version v2.13, Nuxt can auto-import your components when used in your templates.
check the `nuxt.config.js` if components attribute is true then you don't need to import your component on the .vue files.

in your **layouts/default.vue** remove script tag ;-)

```
<template>
  <div>
    <NavBar />
    <Nuxt />
  </div>
</template>
```

If you need to categorize your components by folder, do the following.

goto **nuxt.config.js** and change your components attribute

```
export default {
  components: {
    dirs: [
      '~/components',
      {
        path  : '~/components/site/',
        prefix: 'Site'
      },
      {
        path  : '~/components/admin',
        prefix: 'Admin'
      },
      {
        path  : '~/components/admin/sub',
        prefix: 'AdminSub'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

for example, we have these components :

```
components
  | site
     - header
  | admin
     - header
     - footer
     | sub
        - header
        - footer
```

when we need to call components just separate prefixes and component names with a dash or write camelcase.

in your layouts/default.vue remove script tag ;-)

```
<template>
  <div>

   <!-- with dash -->
   <site-header></site-header>
   <admin-header></admin-header>
   <admin-sub-header></admin-sub-header>


   <!-- cammel -->
   <SiteHeader></SiteHeader>
   <AdminHeader></AdminHeader>
   <AdminSubHeader></AdminSubHeader>

  </div>
</template>
```

> Attention: For Root Components `/components/nav.vue`, We Must Use CammelCase `<Nav/>` and if we call this component like this `<nav/>` it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Yes, I did have ```components: true``` in my nuxt.config.js.

I changed this, and defined the paths and prefixes as you suggested.

The page and nav rendered correctly. However, when I clicked the ```nuxt-link``` the exact same error message occurred.

So I do not think it is related to the component loading.

:-(

Comment: @rlarcombe I test your codes, it works correctly! Look at this 
 https://github.com/kindslayer/rlarcombe-stack-question

Comment: Wow! Thanks Morteza. 
Carefully comparing my set up to yours, the only differerence I can see is  you have 
```modules: ["@nuxtjs/axios"]``` in your nuxt.config.js
I wonder if this might make a difference to how pages are loading.??

Comment: The other module difference I see in nuxt.config.js is that I am using ```"@nuxt/content",```

Comment: @rlarcombe `@nuxt/modules` don't affective to the navigations, but if you are using `@nux/content` in your slug page this can makes an error.